# View in SQL server 2012 with datetime function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-view, sysdatetime

What happens if use SYSUTCDATETIME() in a view? Will the view work correctly? When will it execute the SYSUTCDATETIME function?

For instance I ve created a view from the following select

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.contracts
WHERE (contract_start < SYSUTCDATETIME()) AND (contract_end > SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (`SYSUTCDATETIME()`) will return the value (as any other function) at the time of execution of the view.

Execute this query several time and see for yourself

```
SELECT *, SYSUTCDATETIME() sysutcdatetime FROM contracts
WHERE (contract_start < SYSUTCDATETIME()) AND (contract_end > SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f486a/1)**